# jQuery Mobile: absolute external panel on right side not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to use an external header and two external panels, one at the left, one at the right. The catch: The panels should be always visible on big screens.

I had some problems positioning the panels with an external header (internal works fine), which I could solve for the left panel when using

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 4em;
```

However, this does not work with the right panel, using

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 4em;
```

just places it above the left panel.

You can see this on this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9eb4mekr/

When I use `position: relative; float: right;` instead, the right panel will be on the right but below every other panel (try it in the jsFiddle).

Any Idea on proper positioning of external panels when always visible (big screens)? Plus an external header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Well, not really the problem, but at least the solution, thanks to [Tasos Anastasiou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3430879/tasos-anastasiou): Setting the header position to `fixed`, e.g. with `data-position="fixed"` in the header div will make `relative` positioning work again on **both** panels :)

Here is an updated, working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vhkmok8o/

Comment: You don't say ;-) - it is only possible after one or two days.